# Input line of numbers in haskell and convert to list

Tags: haskell

Basically what is said in the title.

I would like to input

```
4 6 17 4
```

and it would give me the list

```
[4, 6, 17, 4]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
main = do
  ln <- getLine
  let ints = map read (words ln)  :: [Int]
  ... do something with ints...
```

`ints` is a list of `Int` values.

The type signature `:: [Int]` is needed so `read` knows what to return.

Comment: Couldn't match type [] with IO
Expected type: IO Int
  Actual type: [Int] …

Comment: @JohnDoe The code in this answer doesn't cause that error, so it must be in a different part. Which expression does the error message say has the error?

Comment: I just attempted to output the set "ints". And I get this error. I don't understand, I did it as I normally would in the console

Comment: How do I output set to console and not string?